# Difference between a Non-Gaussian Circuit and Gaussian Circuit

Tags: circuit-construction

I am fairly new to this topic and I couldn't find resources that were beginner-friendly. So basically what are the differences between these two?

Comment: it would be helpful if you'd edit the question to add more details about your current understanding of the topic: what did you already read, what exactly you're unclear about etc.

Comment: @glS I am afraid I do not have any knowledge regarding this, I stumbled upon this when I was going through this link - https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_plugins_hybrid.html
EDIT - Any kind of link to study this would be great.

Comment: have you read through the guides pointed out in that link, e.g. https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_gaussian_transformation.html#gaussian-transformation? I feel like you probably want to read through some introduction to continuous variable quantum information/computing, which seems to be a requirement to follow those guides. Basically, you need to know what a Gaussian transformation is. A standard review of the topic is https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3234.

Comment: I've gone through their previous demos and all of them have skipped such information for brevity. However, I will go through the paper you provided, thank-you.